Custom function to create sequential index variable in longitudinal data
This is probably very basic but I'm having a hard time finding an answer to my question in existing posts. I'm working with longitudinal data and need to create a sequential index variable that represents the order of each observation within a repeated ID variable. For example, I want my data to look like this:



ID
Age
Time




1
3.5
1


1
3.7
2


1
4.0
3


2
4.2
1


2
4.5
2


2
4.8
3


3
3.8
1


3
4.1
2


3
4.3
3



In the past, I have successfully created this variable using a for loop that creates a subset of data for each unique ID, then creates a sequential time variable within each subset, and then binds together the resulting subsetted data containing the time variable. I'm guessing there is a more straightforward way to do that, but it has worked for me. Now, I would like to create a custom function that does this so I can easily apply it to any longitudinal data set, but I'm having trouble.
Here's what I have tried with an example data frame:
df <- data.frame(ID=rep.int(1:3,3),Age=c(3.5,4.2,3.8,3.7,4.5,4.1,4.0,4.8,4.3))
df<-df[order(df$ID,df$Age),]
df

create_time_var <-function(data_name){
  holding<-as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=0,ncol=ncol(data_name)+2))
  for (k in unique(data_name$ID)) {
    kid_data <- subset(data_name,data_name$ID%in%k)
    for (t in 1:length(kid_data$Age)){
      kid_data$Time <-seq(from=1, to=length(kid_data$Age))
      kid_data$total <-t
    }
    rbind(kid_data,holding)
  }
}

df_r <-create_time_var(df)
df_r

When I run this, df_r is NULL. Any ideas why? I'm pretty new to creating custom functions so I'm probably missing something obvious. Thanks for any advice!

Here's a FAQ on getting row number by group with dplyr you can do mutate(df, Time = row_number(), .by = ID), or with base R you can do df$Time <- ave(df$ID, df$ID, FUN = seq_along). Custom functions and loops aren't need for something like this.

As for why your approach doesn't work, I think the issue is that you don't assign the result with <-. If you change rbind(kid_data,holding) to holding <- rbind(kid_data,holding), I think it will work, though much less efficiently than the vectorized operations in my previous comment.

@GregorThomas Thank you, I knew there must be a simpler way! I haven't used dplyr much but it would probably make my life a lot easier if started doing so.

It probably would.
